# Increasing maximum upload limit size in ASP.NET Web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload, limit

I'm trying to increase maximum upload limit size in my .NET application...  Current one is 4MB  and I'd like to increase it to 25 MB ...

What I have tried so far (modifying web.config file):

```
<security> 
      <requestFiltering> 
         <!-- maxAllowedContentLength, for IIS, in bytes --> 
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="15728640" ></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering> 
   </security>
```

And:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="25000" />
  </system.web>
```

The second method gives me following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Without any of these method I'm getting this error:

```
Maximum request length exceeded.
```

I'm using .NET Web Forms... And my IIS version is 8 (or above I believe)...

Can someone help me out with this ?

```
  string fileName = fileLanguage.PostedFile.FileName;
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(Server.MapPath("../languages/") + fileName))
                {
                    fileLanguage.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fileLanguage.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                Language language = new Language();
                language.Name = txtLanguageName.Text;
                language.Path = fileName;
                ServiceClass.InsertLanguage(language);
```

Comment: Servers (IIS) normally limit size to around 10M and can't be change in the your client code.

Comment: There has to be a way...

Comment: What's the HResult code on your error?

Comment: In the first method, you are wrapping those tags with <ystem.Webserver tags?

Comment: Not if there is a limit in the server unless you split file.

Comment: This can related to your server side code.Please send your server side code and class library and exception point.

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited I've updated my question with server side code for upload. Can you look into it ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason why the method #2 didn't work... Turns out I had a folder from which I was uploading the files?? And that folder had its own config inside it self... All I had to do was to insert this into my folder's web.config file like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="214748364" />

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note you can limit the file size to something about ~25-30 MB, since it's not recommended to allow users or anyone else to upload large files onto your server.

Cheers!